# How to Read Out txt File with Line Breaks in Node

Tags: node.js, string, formatting, fs

I am trying to output a txt file with line breaks with the fs module in node.

**Trial #1 - UTF8 Encoded**

```
let list = req.body.L_.replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/\r\n/gi, '\\0x0D')

fs.writeFile('./_log/L_.replace(/\"/g, "") + '.txt', list, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
})
```

Input

```
"0  1   ITEM    \r\n    2   2   ITEM    \r\n"
```

Output

```
0   1   ITEM    \u0A0   2   2   ITEM    \u0A
```

Expected Output

```
0   1   ITEM
2   2   ITEM
```

**Trial #2 - Default Node fs Encoding**

```
let list = req.body.L_.replace(/['"]+/g, '')

fs.writeFile('./_log/L_.txt', list, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
})
```

Input

```
"0  1   ITEM    \r\n    2   2   ITEM    \r\n"
```

Output

```
0   1   ITEM    \u0A0   2   2   ITEM    \u0A0
```

Expected Output

```
0   1   ITEM
2   2   ITEM
```

**Trial #3 - Default Node fs Encoding**

```
let list = req.body.L_.replace(/['"]+/g, '')

fs.writeFile('./_log/L_.txt', list, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
})
```

Input

```
"0  1   ITEM    \r  2   2   ITEM    \r"
```

Output

```
0   1   ITEM    2   2   ITEM
```

Expected Output

```
0   1   ITEM
2   2   ITEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit based on comments:

This isn't a nodejs issue. It sounds like encoding for notepad is nonexistent. I recall looking at server logs years ago with nodepad and they where all on one line too. I would suggest using a different text file reader such as Sublime or Notepad++

---

When I run the `.replace` code you have it works fine for me.  Below I have create a test string, from your example.  I have escaped some of the characters that javascript would have interpreted.  Then called your replace method.  Which you can see that the out come was after

```
var s = "\"0  101    1  102        XYZ    15141                          144                Test                      \\n\""
var s2 = s.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
// s2 is 0  101    1  102        XYZ    15141                          144                Test                      \n
```

In your example you aren't calling the replace method.  This leads me to believe you are calling it incorrectly.  The replace method returns a new string leaving original string unaffected.

I would suggest something like this (storage is cheap)

```
var num = JSON.stringify(req.body.number).replace(/\"/g, "");
var list = JSON.stringify(req.body.list).replace(/['"]+/g, "");
list = list.replace(/[ ]+/g, "\t"); // Replaces the spaces with a single tab
fs.writeFile('./_log' + num + '.txt', list, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
})
```

Comment: In you post you said you wanted to keep the line breaks, so I did not replace them

Comment: If you want to replace the newlines as well, change the 1st replace to include the newline in the replace   .replace(`['"\\n]+/g, "");`

Comment: When I write out the files using ```\r\n``` no line breaks are loaded in by Notepad.  It loads as one continuous string.

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: ```0   1   ITEM   \r\n   2   2   ITEM   \r\n```

Comment: I see you've updated your question, thank you that is much clearer.

I wrote a little 4 lines to test this and it seems to work fine.  A few things to point out, utf8 is the default encoding, so your two trials should act the same.  '\0x0D' is the hex encoding so with utf8 that wont work.  Honestly, `\n` OR `\r` should work fine. I would guess Windows is doing something funky.  Can you open in wordpad instead of notpad?


    `var fs = require('fs');`
    `var test = '0 1 ITEM \r\n 2 2 ITEM \r\n';`
    `var list = test.replace(/\r\n/gi, '\n');`
    `fs.writeFile('test.txt', list);`

Comment: With ```\r``` it formats properly in Wordpad and Excel, but not Notepad.

Comment: This isn't a nodejs issue.  It sounds like encoding for notepad is nonexistent.  I recall looking at server logs years ago with nodepad and they where all on one line too.  I would suggest using a different text file reader such as Sublime or Notepad++

Comment: Yes sir. How would you like me to flag this question?

Comment: Ill update my answer to reflect the issue.  If you would like to still try to get an answer if you NEED to use notepad.  I would open another question with different tags

Comment: I don't need to use Notepad, was just using it to debug and it ended up being the bug...